# how to make a huge array visible to all worker nodes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apriori

I am using Spark Java API to implement A-Priori algorithm described in [MMD, chapter 6](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch6.pdf), and the algorithm will need to involve a huge `int` array like this:

```
frequent_item[i] = x, // i is a big integer, x is some integer
```

Now, how to make this array visible to all the worker nodes in the cluster?  more specifically,

1. can `sc.broadcast(frequent_item)` be used for this purpose?
2. does this mean this huge array will have a copy in the memory of each worker node?
3. what would be the best practice guideline for things like this?

Thanks, as always!

Comment: Broadcast variable will place a copy of the array in every executor. It doesn't make sense to have a copy of huge array in every executor.

What is your use case here? Are you going to join this array with other RDD/DF? If you are going to perform just filter/transformation on this array, then you can parallelize the array and make it a distributed data set like RDD or Dataframe.

Comment: the array is like a dictionary for the worker node. Each worker node gets a partition/chunk of the file it works on, and from time to time, it has to check this dictionary to make sure something. Since it is hard to tell which partition of the original file the worker will get, it is simply easier to keep the whole dictionary available for the worker.

Comment: In that case, try to estimate the size of your array using org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator.estimate(your obj). If the size is reasonable then you can use broadcast else you will have to consider distributing your array over your cluster.  By using broadcast we are avoiding the movement of data over the network, but if your object is too large to fit in memory of a machine, then you will get OOM error. Also keep in mind, the broadcast will store your array in "Storage Memory".

Comment: Thank you for explaining this patiently and clearly, learned a lot. Many thanks!!

Comment: You are most welcome :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcast is the right approach.

1. `val y = sc.broadcast(frequent_item)` will broadcast frequent_item
   and y will become `Broadcast[Array[Int]]` and the value can be
   accessed by using: `y.value`

   To access (i)th element the code is 
   `val element = y.value(i)` // scala notation
2. Does this mean this huge array will have a copy in the memory of
   each worker node? Yes there will be copy of the data in each node.
3. Best practise 
   a.)estimate the size of the broadcast variable and determine the executor and driver memories with this in consideration.
   b.) broadcast only when needed
   c.) unpersist once the broadcast variable is not used.

For more information read [Spark Brodcast](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html)